# Using .htaccess to replace backslash in URL with forward-slash

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I realise that a backslash should never appear in a URL in a form other than a URL escape code, however in this case the URL's are being generated by a .NET application for generating flashbooks.  I have contacted the developer of this application with a bug report.

In the interim i would like to use .htaccess to rewrite the offending backslashes.

This is how the URLs appear in fiddler debugging proxy.

```
www.example.com/folder/folder/thumbs%5C1.jpg
```

I am using Firefox and it looks as though Firefox is translating them into the URL encoded equivalent ( \ == %5C1 ).  Interestingly IE translates the backslash into a forward-slash automatically (not adhering to standards but convenient in this case).

Is there a way to use .htaccess to rewrite all \ to /?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)\\(.*)
RewriteRule .* %1/%2 [R=301]
```