# Replacing "/" in URL querystring to avoid 404 in htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a url which has two parameters and I have rewritten them in the htaccess file with this

`RewriteRule ^subscriber/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/?$ subscriber/index.php?id=$1&name=$2 [NC,L]`

The name in some cases contains a "/" which the browser is treating like another parameter and is giving me a 404 page. Is there a way to replace "/" to something else using the htaccess file?

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you mean by the name containing a "/"? Because it looks like the grouping `([^/.]+)` won't match a "/"

Comment: You can check this link http://www.etable.in/subscriber/374/24/7 which returns a 404 but if you try this http://www.etable.in/subscriber/374/24-7 you can see the page

Comment: So in the last grouping, if there are more than one slash, you want that slash to be replaced with a dash?

Comment: Yes thats what i want to do. I want to do this in the htaccess if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting this in the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)name=([^&]*)/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?%1name=%2-%3 [L]

# Change your existing rule a bit to account for the slash (plus a possible trailing slash):
RewriteRule ^subscriber/([^/.]+)/(.+?)/?$ /subscriber/index.php?id=$1&name=$2 [NC,L]
```

This will make the first "folder" in the URI after **subscriber/**, the `id` param, and *everything* after that except for a trailing slash be the `name` param. The first set of rules then repeatedly clean out the `name` param, replacing `/` with `-`.

Comment: Thanks Jon. This is taking me to the root folder of my site. Have a look at the url. Maybe will have to change a bit in the condition. will have a look

Comment: And its working now. Thanks a lot! If you are a foodie, please join etable. Its a foodie network.

Comment: @Rohit Yeah you're right, forgot to include a `subscriber` in the last rule.

Answer (score 0):

You can use urlencode() function when setting the name variable

```
$name = 'Michael/';
$name = urlencode($name);
// will return you Michael%08 or something like this
```

Accordingly with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3055043/using-htaccess-to-replace-backslash-in-url-with-forward-slash) the solution for .htaccess might be:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)\\(.*)
RewriteRule .* %1/%2 [R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer Matei. Is there a way to do that using a rewrite condition in htaccess?

Comment: Welcome, I've edited my answer for adding your htaccess solution

Comment: Its still giving me a 404 error. here is the link. http://www.etable.in/subscriber/374/24/7