# NginX: rewrite backslashes to Forward-slashes

Tags: nginx, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to write NginX rewrite rule to convert all Backslashes to forward-slashes.

Something exactly like: [Using .htaccess to replace backslash in URL with forward-slash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3055043/using-htaccess-to-replace-backslash-in-url-with-forward-slash)

however, I am working in NginX while above link refers to Apache.

I migrated my application from Windows IIS to Linux Tomcat and hence I need to get this done.
My URL has multiple Backslashes which gets resolved fine in IE and Chrome but Firefox is resolving them to its Unicode **%5C** and hence I need to rewrite.

My sample URL in WIndows/IIS: **https://doman.com/company/.\images\company\companylogo.png**

When I moved stuff to Linux/Tomcat, above URL works in Chrome and IE, but Firefox is converting above backslashes to **%5C**. So Firefox is trying to resolve: **https://doman.com/company/.%5Cimages%5Ccompany%5Ccompanylogo.png**

And needless to say, Firefox fails to load the image.

Here is what I tried so far in my nginX configuration (Once statement at a time)):

```
rewrite \ / permanent;
rewrite \\ \/ permanent;  # with escaping thinking it might help
rewrite (.*)\(.*)\(.*)\(.*)  $1/$2/$3/$4 permanent;
rewrite (.*)\(.*)\(.*)\(.*)  $1\/$2\/$3\/$4 permanent;
```

Howcer , none seem to work and last 2 statements are throwing NginX configuration Error.

Any pointers would be of great help. There are thousands such URLs and I cannot imagine of converting all of them into Forward-Slash'd style.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I figured it out myself.

First off, in NginX, a **`backslash`** needs to be **escaped twice**. Nginx Uses **`Lua`** launguage module extensively for parsing request. So, NginX config parser as well as Lua module will strip off the escaping backslashes. Hence need to escape it twice.

This is wrong: **`\\`**

This is Correct: **`\\\`**

This part bugged me for 2 days as I was following typical PCRE standards for escaping characters and NginX would throw regex error at me.

More about this behaviour is explained here: http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpLuaModule#Special_PCRE_Sequences

Now, over to my question:

Source URL: https://domain.com/company/.\images\company\companylogo.png

Redirected URL: https://domain.com/company/./images/company/companylogo.png

I wanted to convert all `\` to `/` in above URL. So, for this purpose, below `rewrite` rule is needed:

```
rewrite ^/(.+)\\\(.+)\\\(.+)\\\(.+)$ /$1/$2/$3/$4 redirect;
```

Above rule will do a single redirect (HTTP Code 302) and will get all the three `\` converted to `/`.

However, If you have varying number of `\` in the URL, then above rule may(not) work. Hence in that case, use below rule to convert `ALL` `\` to `/`

```
rewrite ^/(.+)\\\(.+)$ /$1/$2 redirect;
```

Please note that, with above rule in place multiple redirects (HTTP Code 302) will happen causing some latency. The number of redirects will be equal to number of `\` in the source URL. This would work on my URL too. But then it would have done the redirect for 3 times (as I have 3 backslashes in my URL). So, I am good with the 1st rule I mentioned above.

Nonetheless, I had a great learning all along and I understand NginX better now.

Here are few (out of hundreds of) links which helped solving this issue:

http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpLuaModule

https://blog.engineyard.com/2011/useful-rewrites-for-nginx

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location

http://blog.rackcorp.com/2010/05/nginx-location-and-rewrite-configuration-made-easy/

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-bsd-nginx-redirect-url-http-301-status-code/